# Go Hood saving to Postgres, but not sure where

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a SaveRequest method that takes and `http.Request` and then, supposedly, saves it (right now just the path) to a postgres database:

```
func (logger *PostgresLogger) SaveRequest(req *http.Request) {
  os.Stdout.Write([]byte("Saving to PGDB\n"))
  request := db.Requests { Path: req.URL.Path }
  transaction := logger.dbConnection.Begin()
  Id, saveError := transaction.Save(&request)
  if saveError != nil {
    panic(saveError)
  }

  os.Stdout.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%v\n", Id)))

  transactionError := logger.dbConnection.Commit()
  if transactionError != nil {
    panic(transactionError)
  }
}
```

That `dbConnection` comes from loading a [Hood](https://github.com/eaigner/hood) config file:

```
func New(prefix string) (PostgresLogger) {
  dbConnection, err := hood.Load("/Users/ls/Dropbox/programming/go/src/postgres_logger/db/config.json", "development")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  return PostgresLogger{ prefix: prefix, dbConnection: dbConnection }
}
```

Cool. So when I start the reverse proxy and ask it to save incoming requests, I see this (sample, where logs are prefixed by RVSPRXY):

```
Saving to PGDB
56
RVSPRXY (1368315177148901322):
[::1]:51142 GET /css/editor.css

Saving to PGDB
RVSPRXY (1368315177149851787):
[::1]:51143 GET /js/handlebars.min.js

Saving to PGDB
RVSPRXY (1368315177150164615):
[::1]:51140 GET /css/mercury.bundle.css

Saving to PGDB
RVSPRXY (1368315177150358938):
[::1]:51141 GET /css/mercury_regions.bundle.css

Saving to PGDB
RVSPRXY (1368315177150776986):
[::1]:51144 GET /js/jquery-2.0.0.min.js

Saving to PGDB
57
58
59
60
```

So we can see it incrementing the id being returned from Save, but I look in the logging_development database and there are no records.

Stopping and restarting the server continues to increment the ids from where it left off, so it seems like it is actually saving, but where?

**Update**

Here is the development config:

```
{
   "development": {
     "driver": "postgres",
     "source": "user=logging dbname=logging_development sslmode=disable"
   }
 }
```

And some of what PGAdmin shows for connections:

```
5289    logging logging_development 2013-05-11 17:54:48.700467-06   127.0.0.1:51403 INSERT INTO "requests" ("path", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  
5290    logging logging_development 2013-05-11 17:54:48.746065-06   127.0.0.1:51414 INSERT INTO "requests" ("path", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  
5291    logging logging_development 2013-05-11 17:54:48.747876-06   127.0.0.1:51415 INSERT INTO "requests" ("path", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  
5292    logging logging_development 2013-05-11 17:54:48.748086-06   127.0.0.1:51416 INSERT INTO "requests" ("path", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  
5293    logging logging_development 2013-05-11 17:54:48.74866-06
```

Edit: fixed a bug checking the wrong error (not the cause of the issue)

Comment: 1) where should the data go according to config.json? and 2) you could use pgadmin to check what db clients are connected to, and what queries they're actually executing.

Comment: I added the config file. It should be going to logging_development, and the statistics for the server seem to show that this is the case.

Comment: `os.Stdout.Write([]byte("Saving to PGDB\n"))` can be better witten as `fmt.Println("Saving to PGDB")` btw

Comment: You only fixed one of the bugs. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
func (logger *PostgresLogger) SaveRequest(req *http.Request) {
    os.Stdout.Write([]byte("Saving to PGDB\n"))
    request := db.Requests{Path: req.URL.Path}
    transaction := logger.dbConnection.Begin()
    Id, saveError := transaction.Save(&request)
    if saveError != nil {
        panic(saveError)
    }
    os.Stdout.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%v\n", Id)))
    transactionError := logger.dbConnection.Commit()
    if saveError != nil {
        panic(transactionError)
    }
}
```

What results do you get if you write:

```
func (logger *PostgresLogger) SaveRequest(req *http.Request) {
    os.Stdout.Write([]byte("Saving to PGDB\n"))
    request := db.Requests{Path: req.URL.Path}
    transaction := logger.dbConnection.Begin()
    Id, saveError := transaction.Save(&request)
    if saveError != nil {
        panic(saveError)
    }
    os.Stdout.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%v\n", Id)))
    // commit transaction
    transactionError := transaction.Commit()
    // check transactionError
    if transactionError != nil {
        panic(transactionError)
    }
}
```

Comment: To avoid people playing "find the difference", any chance you can mention what you've changed and the rationale behind why?

Comment: He noticed that I assigned a transactionError, but then checked for the saveError. I noticed that as well and fixed it, but am still getting the same results :(

Comment: Did you copy and paste the proposed code, which `Commit`s the `transaction` and checks `transactionError`?

Comment: Is this a question or an answer? Or an answer formulated as a question? - anyway, with Stackoverflows Q&A format questions to localize problems should be posted as comments to the question, and not as answers. Only answers should be posted as answers.